# login is not pulling through LoginStudentNumber from the view to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication

When i run my login I cannot seem to pull through the LoginStudentNumber. It pulls through the password, but not the LoginStudentNumber. Please see what exaclty is wrong with my code.

Login Controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using RMS.DAL;
using RMS.Models;

namespace RMS.Controllers
{
    public class LoginController : Controller
    {
        RMSContext db = new RMSContext();


        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
        {
            ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
            return View();
        }

        //
        // POST: /Account/Login
        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]

        public ActionResult Login(Login model, int? LoginStudentNumber, string LoginPassword)
        {
            //Login user = db.Logins
            Login user = db.Logins.Find(LoginStudentNumber);

            if (user == null)
            {
                ViewBag.Name1 = "Invalid User ID";
                return View();
            }
            else
            {
                if (user.LoginPassword.Equals(LoginPassword))
                {

                    return View("../Home/Index", model);


                }
                else
                {
                    ViewBag.Name2 = "Invalid Password";
                    return View();
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Login View:

```
@model RMS.Models.Login

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="Creative - Bootstrap 3 Responsive Admin Template">
    <meta name="author" content="GeeksLabs">
    <meta name="keyword" content="Creative, Dashboard, Admin, Template, Theme, Bootstrap, Responsive, Retina, Minimal">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.png">

    <title>Login</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->

    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!-- bootstrap theme -->

    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!--external css-->
    <!-- font icon -->

    <link href="~/Content/elegant-icons-style.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <link href="~/Content/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!-- Custom styles -->

    <link href="~/Content/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <link href="~/Content/style-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="js/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>

<body style="background-color:white">
    <img src="~/img/thrupps.png" style="width: 300px; height: 200px; margin: 0px 490px 0px 490px; " />
    <div class="col-md-12">

        <div class="login-wrap">
            @using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Login", System.Web.Mvc.FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "login-form" }))
            {
                <p class="login-img"><i class="icon_lock_alt"></i></p>
                <div>
                    @ViewBag.Name1
                </div>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="icon_profile"></i></span>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.LoginStudentNumber, "LoginStudentNumber", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                </div>
                <div>
                    @ViewBag.Name2
                </div>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="icon_key_alt"></i></span>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.LoginPassword, "LoginPassword", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                </div>

                <input type="submit" id="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block " value="Login" />

            }
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Login Model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace RMS.Models
{
    public class Login
    {
        public int LoginID { get; set; }
        [Required] 

        public int LoginStudentNumber { get; set; }
        [Required] 

        public string LoginPassword { get; set; }

    }
}
```

and also to add, when I type the following code, I identifies "Logins" and not "Login" even though my table in titled "Login".

```
Login user = db.Logins.Find(LoginStudentNumber);
```

Comment: This is not an appropriate comment

Answer (score 0):

Whilst Michael Fung's answer did tickle me I believe this answer is what you're after...

Your logic action's parameter is spelt incorrectly. You put `LoginStudentNumer` when it should be `LoginStudentNumber`

```
    public ActionResult Login(Login model, int? LoginStudentNumer, string LoginPassword)
```

**Update**

You can ensure the client enters a number by utilising the type attribute and setting its value to number.

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.LoginStudentNumber, "LoginStudentNumber", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", type = "number" })
```

**Update 2**

> still having a problem. when i run the login page, it doesn't take me
>   to the home page when my username and password is correct,

The reason it doesn't take you to your home page is because the following is invalid

```
 return View("../Home/Index", model);
```

You should be returning a redirect to the browser

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
```

> nor does it show me errors for when my username and password is
>   incorrect. could there be something wrong in the controller.

If you want to display the errors you can return the model along with any model state Errors.

> ```
>     public ActionResult Login(Login model, int? LoginStudentNumber, string LoginPassword)       
>     {
>         //Login user = db.Logins
>         Login user = db.Logins.Find(LoginStudentNumer);
>
>         if (user == null)
>         {
>             ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid User Id");
>
>             return View(model);
>         }
>
>
>
>         if (user.LoginPassword.Equals(LoginPassword))
>         {
>
>             return RedirectToAction("Index","Home");
>
>
>         }
>
>         ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid Password");
>         return View(model);
>
>     }
> ```

Then in your view you would need to output the error message but using...

```
@Html.ValidationSummary()
```

Comment: thanks. I did spot that mistake, however I am facing the same problem. (Sorry I realize that I should have updated my question)

Comment: Are you sure? I've copied you code and its working find for me. Make sure you're actually typing in an integer otherwise it will not get bound

Comment: still having a problem. when i run the login page, it doesn't take me to the home page when my username and password is correct, nor does it show me errors for when my username and password is incorrect. could there be something wrong in the controller.

Comment: OK i've added a but more! If you need anything else you might be better off creating a new question as this is diverging